# serialversionUID does not match

Tags: java, serialization, serialversionuid

[image]

I am fairly new to java and I have a class `Products` that is `Serializable`. I do not know what I did, but my programs stopped working and gave me this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.InvalidClassException: cockeb.Product;
local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 1288455942608122525,
local class serialVersionUID = -558553967080513790

at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:616)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1829)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1713)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1986)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:791)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1058)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2122)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2013)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422
```

I searched around and found ways to declare it, but that doesn't help me right now.  I even went as far as opening a new project and just copying the text in each class from the non working project and pasting it in the new project, but i still get the same error. I am getting this error across all of my projects (they use the same `Serializable` class) I need to know what i did to do this so it doesn't happen again, and what i can do to fix it.  I already tried to declare the `serialversionUID` and that did not work.

**Product Class**

```
package cockeb;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class Product implements Comparable<Product>, Serializable {

private String upc;
private String shortDetails;
private String longDetails;
private BigDecimal price;
private Integer stock;

public String getUpc() {
    return upc;
}

public void setUpc(String upc) {
    this.upc = upc;
}

public String getShortDetails() {
    return shortDetails;
}

public void setShortDetails(String shortDetails) {
    this.shortDetails = shortDetails;
}

public String getLongDetails() {
    return longDetails;
}

public void setLongDetails(String longDetails) {
    this.longDetails = longDetails;
}

public BigDecimal getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(BigDecimal price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public Integer getStock() {
    return stock;
}

public void setStock(Integer stock) {
    this.stock = stock;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Product t) {
    return this.getUpc().compareTo(t.getUpc());
}
}
```

Comment: please post your Product class.

Comment: thank you for looking at this, I  had never got this error before

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put this line in your class and everything should be ok!

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = -558553967080513790L;
```

That's because you implements `Serializable` interface in the `Product` class and if you do not define `serialVersionUID` in the specific class, there's no guarantee that different machines use the same id also in different versions of class the autogenerated serialVersionUIDs will also be different.
Actually **The default serialVersionUID computation is highly sensitive to class details and may vary from different JVM implementation, and result in an unexpected InvalidClassExceptions during the deserialization process.**

**Edited** Read this -- Serializable interface's docs:

> If a serializable class does not explicitly declare a
>   serialVersionUID, then the serialization runtime will calculate a
>   default serialVersionUID value for that class based on various aspects
>   of the class, as described in the Java(TM) Object Serialization
>   Specification. However, it is strongly recommended that all
>   serializable classes explicitly declare serialVersionUID values, since
>   the default serialVersionUID computation is highly sensitive to class
>   details that may vary depending on compiler implementations, and can
>   thus result in unexpected InvalidClassExceptions during
>   deserialization. Therefore, to guarantee a consistent serialVersionUID
>   value across different java compiler implementations, a serializable
>   class must declare an explicit serialVersionUID value. It is also
>   strongly advised that explicit serialVersionUID declarations use the
>   private modifier where possible, since such declarations apply only to
>   the immediately declaring class--serialVersionUID fields are not
>   useful as inherited members. Array classes cannot declare an explicit
>   serialVersionUID, so they always have the default computed value, but
>   the requirement for matching serialVersionUID values is waived for
>   array classes.

Good Luck!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143599/discussion-on-answer-by-mohammad-reza-khatami-serialversionuid-does-not-match).