# Hibernate OneToMany relation is PersistentBag instead of List

Tags: java, hibernate, ejb, wildfly, rmi

I am developing an application in javafx that connects via RMI with an EAR. This EAR connects to a SQLServer DB and maps POJOS using hibernate.

These POJOS contain bidirectional OneToMany and ManyToOne relationships. As a consequence these relationships are mapped as List .

**Company.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Company")
public class Company implements Serializable{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name="id_company",nullable = false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "company",cascade = CascadeType.ALL )
@ElementCollection
private List<Client> Clients;

//GETTERS&SETTERS   

}
```

**Client.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Client")
public class Client implements Serializable{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name="id_client",nullable = false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id; 

@ManyToOne
private Company company;

//GETTERS&SETTERS   

}
```

When I execute this, T being Company:

```
public default T selectById(Serializable id, Class<T> entityClass,Session session)throws HibernateException {
    T obj = null;
    obj = session.get(entityClass, id);
    return obj;
}
```

The result is the POJO with all the corresponding information, but in debug view see this:

[image: screen]

The object is successfully instantiated and my desktop application receives the object perfectly, but if the object sent it to the server again using a method that receives as a parameter the object Company then I have this Error.

```
javax.ejb.EJBException: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: serialVersionUID does not match!
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.AssociationImpl.receiveInvocationRequest(AssociationImpl.java:128)
at org.jboss.ejb.protocol.remote.EJBServerChannel$ReceiverImpl.handleInvocationRequest(EJBServerChannel.java:450)
at org.jboss.ejb.protocol.remote.EJBServerChannel$ReceiverImpl.handleMessage(EJBServerChannel.java:188)
at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.RemoteConnectionChannel.lambda$handleMessageData$3(RemoteConnectionChannel.java:430)
at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl$TrackingExecutor.lambda$execute$0(EndpointImpl.java:926)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: serialVersionUID does not match!
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractClassResolver.resolveClass(AbstractClassResolver.java:108)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadClassDescriptor(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1025)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadNewObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1354)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:275)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:223)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.readFields(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1856)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doInitSerializable(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1769)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadNewObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1397)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:275)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:208)
at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractObjectInput.readObject(AbstractObjectInput.java:41)
at org.jboss.ejb.protocol.remote.EJBServerChannel$RemotingInvocationRequest.getRequestContent(EJBServerChannel.java:805)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.AssociationImpl.receiveInvocationRequest(AssociationImpl.java:126)
... 7 more
Caused by: an exception which occurred:
    in field com.persistence.pojo.Company.Clients
in object com.persistence.pojo.Company@47368172
in object of type com.persistence.pojo.Company
```

I am using a Wildfly10.x server.
The version of hibernatecore is 5.2.17.Final

I am sorry if it is very poorly explained but it is that the project is quite complex, in essence I would need hibernate to map to List object instead of to Persistentbag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here, is that the object you get from hibernate is of some hibernate proxy class, and not your actual entity class. This is normal behaviour for hibernate.
This proxy class is autogenerated, and so is it's serialVersionUID.

In general, it is not a good practice to serialize/send entity class objects directly, because of such problems, but also because of problems with lazy initialization and all those connected with having objects bound to entity manager context.

The most common solution is to create "data transport objects" or DTOs which may have the same fields (or very similar - like replace enums with Strings etc, depends on what you need), and nothing else. based on your example, you can have a class like that:

```
public class CompanyDTO implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private int id;

private List<ClientDTO> Clients;

//GETTERS&SETTERS   

}
```

(by analogy you need to create ClientDTO class too).

Use this class instead, for outside (where outside is not necessarily remote, just wherever you need to detach from EM context) communication.

You can fill it by hand, or by any other means (like with reflection using BeanUtils, constructor with Company argument which copies properties [this I would not advise, as it interrupts application layer seperation, but for the purpose of this conversation it is a valid way to do that]). The only thing important is that you fill it from within entity manager context

Comment: My idea at first was to not use DTO and use the lazy initialization instead.
For example if I need a list of companies from the client I would call a method that returns a list of companies and how they have lazy initialization are less heavy. On the other hand, if I want to enter one of those companies to show their data on a screen I would make another request to obtain a company through their id that would initialize the list of clients before sending it.

By your comment I understand that there is no way to force hibernate to create the list without the proxy. do not?

Thank you.

Comment: No, to my knowledge there is no way to do that

Comment: @Zeromus If I do what you said in the second comment, the collection is still a PersistentBag. And the first comment I did not understand well.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Client` Entity you need to generate dynamic serialVersionUID, generate one like this

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = -558553967080513790L;
```

You can see [in this link](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-generate-serialversionuid/) how to generate the serialVersionUID.
For more information see this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43828566/serialversionuid-does-not-match).

Comment: I also had serialVersionUID configuration as you say and gives me the same error.

Comment: Always using the same ID, such as 1L means that in the future, if the class definition is changed which causes changes to the structure of the serialized object, there will be a good chance that problems when trying to deserialize an object.
So, try to use generate serial version ID. Do not use 1L.

Comment: The idea is to generate an ID that is unique to a certain version of an class, which is then changed when there are new details added to the class, such as a new field, which would affect the structure of the serialized object.

Comment: I know the reasons why the serialversionUID exists and why it should be unique for each class. Thanks for telling me, but as I said before as much as if it is with a unique serial as if it is 1L the error that I explained before keeps coming up. Thank you.

Comment: Add default constructor to your classes and try cleaning the project .class files and rebuild the project

Comment: using a different serialVersionUID will not change a thing. The problem here, is that the object that OP is trying to serialize is actually of another class than it seems (hibernate proxy class)