# Hibernate Serialization failing

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss7.x

I have a Java client-server application with a Swing front end and JBoss on the back end.  It was running under JBoss 6.4 with Hibernate 4.2 and now it's failing following an update to JBoss 7.2 with Hibernate 5.3.7.  I'm getting an exception when the client is trying to serialize the objects to send them back to the server.

```
Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: serialVersionUID does not match!
at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractClassResolver.resolveClass(AbstractClassResolver.java:108)
    ...
Caused by: an exception which occurred:
    in field com.company.app.model.Vehicle.parts
    in object com.company.app.model.Vehicle@75e4da10
    in object of type com.company.app.model.Vehicle
```

It appears that the error is coming from the parts collection which is a collection of Part entities that is not lazy loaded. Hibernate creates proxy objects with their own serialVersionUIDs and I read that this can cause this error.

Also note that this happens even if the parts collection is empty.

I am evicting the Vehicle object from the session before sending it to the client.  I tried calling Hibernate.unproxy on the parts collection and on the Vehicle object but it didn't make any difference.  I was finally able to get it to work by creating a new List, adding the parts to it, and then replacing the parts list in the Vehicle object with that new list.  This seems like a hack though and a real pain when there are a lot of entities with multiple relationships.

I read an answer to [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50328894/1299131) where it was suggested to use Data Transport Objects and not send the Hibernate entity objects themselves.  However this worked fine under the previous version of Hibernate.  I've gone through the Hibernate 5.3 documentation and migration guides I didn't see any changes that would cause this.

Any ideas on what's wrong or what else I should try?